# Is to possible to use > (greater than) condition in Query String

Tags: query-string

I need data greater than April 2014 so I need to put filter in the query string. Is there any way to use `>` sign ?

I need something like this:

```
filterField1="MonthYear"&FilterValue1>"April2014"
```